# Where is Firefox's URL processor?

Tags: firefox

After 3 days digging in this Mozilla NSS and the Firefox source codes (and some extensions and running the SSLsample codes too), I'm clearly lost now.

My intention is just to do simple thing. To divert any https request from Firefox to my very own callback functions. In which, my callbacks here have some information for the NSS/SSL to work with.

My only problem is, where is Firefox's code for processing the https URL. I mean, when we key in the https address at the address bar, we press Enter. I just need access to the source that triggers at that point (after we press Enter). Somehow, I can intercept any request for https URLs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to [intercept the data](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Mozilla_Embedding_FAQ/How_do_I...#How_do_I_watch.2fintercept_a_load_before_it_happens.3f), right?  You'll want to play around with [this interface](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/uriloader/base/nsIURIContentListener.idl).

Answer (score 0):

not sure, if it helps, but I asked this question:

[XULRunner: Prevent links to arbitrary domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036912/xulrunner-prevent-links-to-arbitrary-domains)

Maybe it could be sufficient for your task to use the method explained in the first answer. However, it is an all-JavaScript solution.

Cheers,